# I Don't get the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message from other applications

Tags: c, api, dll, hook, subclassing

In my C-Dll there is a Windows hook:

```
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, CallWndProc, hinstance, 0);
```

With this Callback method:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

...
CWPSTRUCT* cw = reinterpret_cast<CWPSTRUCT*>(lParam);
myfile << "CallWndProc allg. " << cw->message << "\n";

if (cw->message == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
{
    // I don't get the message here
}
}
```

I get all Windows messages except the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message. I want to modify the maximum size of a window.
How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message is actually being sent via Spy++ or similar program?

Also note that this message [is not sent](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/09/9466834.aspx) when `MoveWindow` is called.